# Python SQlite3 Update function, sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to update an item in my database for the relevant field which is identified by an OrderID.

```
 cursor.execute("UPDATE Customer_Orders SET Progress=?, WHERE OrderID=?", 
 ("Completed", tableOrderInfo[0],))
```

However, I keep getting this syntax error and I don't know why.

```
 sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Customer_Orders SET Progress=? WHERE OrderID=?
```

> remove the comma before WHERE.

See more about UPDATE in SQL [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).